# Boto3 not loading aws credentials file on windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, credentials

I am trying to use the credentials file to load my aws credentials on windows.
I am using boto3, and it works properly when I set the credentials on windows system environment variables, but not when I created the credentials file in the %UserProfile%/.aws folder

The content of my credentials file is as follows ,(replaced my real tokens with XXXX):

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXX
aws_session_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Is there any way to trace the precedence boto3 uses to retrieve the credentials? Any thoughts on why it is not picking the values from the file?

Comment: If you run the awscli (e.g. `aws s3 ls`) allowing it to pick up your default credentials from %UserProfile%/.aws/credentials, does it work? Are you running your boto3 app with the same effective user represented by %UserProfile%? And when you say it's not working, what symptoms (error message) do you see?

Comment: FYI here is the [precedence order for credential retrieval](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html). Note that environment variables precede credentials/config files.

Comment: What error are you experiencing? What happens if you run `aws iam get-user`? Does it return the credentials information you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this steps:

1. pip install awscli
2. aws configure -> put all your credentials
3. Then try again and the error go away.

Comment: Because sometimes if you not install and configure first aws from pip3 the runtime environment of python can't see the credentials in the file...

Comment: I'm not aware of any dependency that boto3 has on awscli. It should be sufficient to simply create ~/.aws/credentials and optionally ~/.aws/config files manually.

Comment: the problem is he said he have that file

Answer (score -1):

C:\Users\USERNAME.aws\credentials on Windows. This file can contain the credential details for the default profile and any named profiles.

Comment: OP isn't having issues finding their `credentials` file. Their issue is that boto3 isn't reading it.